# Javascript - Inject code into iframe containing 3rd party site

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, reverse-proxy

**CONTEXT**

I am loading a third party website (e.g. google.com) into an iframe on my site. I would like to be able to apply my own script (e.g. jquery) to the page in order to change DOM elements, but obviously cannot due to CORS policy. I know that the solution to this is a reverse proxy but I haven't seen any simple versions or walkthroughs that explain how something like this is set up.

**QUESTION**

So far I've found the following two packages that try to solve this problem:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/corsproxy
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

I'm not sure exactly what the simplest application of these would be to an iframe - is there an example/jsfiddle that shows this in action?

Comment: you would run corsproxy from command line with port options etc, then set your iframe src to `http://yourserver:corsport/google.com/` which should allow you to access the contents of the iframe. You may have to set up a reverseproxy in nginx or apache so that you can give the appearance that your corsproxy and other script are running on the same port.

Comment: Great, thank you @ShamSUP - so corsproxy inserts the CORS headers into the site that's being loaded and nginx performs the actual reverse proxy? I'm not sure I understand what each piece is doing here...

Comment: Corsproxy is an application that loads whatever url you pass to it. It runs on your server in order to bypass cors rules for cross-domain iframes. The nginx/apache reverse proxy would be just in case cors prevents access to the same domain but a different port.